# Expected AMQPS protocol when TLS is enabled

Tags: rabbitmq

I have conducted an experiment with RabbitMQ. An experiment looks like this. I send a single message from a producer through a broker to a consumer, with two use cases `TLS enabled` and `TLS disabled`. For both experiments, I captured network packets with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

My expectations for these two experiments are as follow:

1. TLS disabled

   I expect to capture [AMQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) packets.
2. TLS enabled

   I expect to capture [AMQPS](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-wireshark.html) packets.

The first experiment works! In the second experiment, I see encrypted packets with `TLS v1.3` protocol, not `AMQPS` protocol as I would expect. It looks like RabbitMQ switches protocol from AMQP to TLS when encrypted. If so, then why bother with AMQPS in the first place?

Comment: If you do the same thing with HTTPS, you will see TLS packets instead of HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

AMQPS **is** AMQP over TLS.

You must configure Wireshark to decode the TLS data - https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS

Answer (score 0):

@Luke Bakken answer is correct, although I still need to configure Wireshark to decrypt the data

Let me give more context to his answer. Namely, AMQPS is a label (convention). When we say "AMQPS", we're referring to "AMQP over SSL/TLS". So AMPQS is not a different protocol per se; it's just AMQP traffic encrypted with SSL/TLS.

When you enable TLS for AMQP (application-level protocol) then, it's wrapped (tunneled) through TLS. This is why you'll see "TLS v1.3" packets in Wireshark for the encrypted traffic. The AMQP traffic is there, but it's now encrypted inside the TLS packets.

Saying all that, @Marat Mkhitaryan observation (comment) is correct too! There is no dedicated HTTPS protocol to be seen in Wireshark. Instead, it's HTTP over (wrapped/tunneled) SSL/TLS - effectively TLS v1.n.